# Camel servlet no spring example <to> tag with http uri?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I deployed camel-example-servlet-tomcat-no-spring example to tomcat. it was worked fine. I changed camel-config.xml but I'm getting bellow error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri: /camel-example/camel/hello. If you are forwarding/bridging http endpoints, then enable the bridgeEndpoint option on the endpoint: Endpoint[https://www.google.com]
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.createMethod(HttpProducer.java:376)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:91)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1760)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**Actual camel-config.xml:**

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="servlet:///hello"/>
    <choice>
      <when>
        <header>name</header>
        <transform>
          <simple>Hello ${header.name} how are you?</simple>
        </transform>
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        <transform>
          <constant>Add a name parameter to uri, eg ?name=foo</constant>
        </transform>
      </otherwise>
    </choice>
  </route>

</routes>
```

**Changed camel-config.xml:**

```
 <routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="servlet:///hello"/>
    <loadBalance>
    <weighted roundRobin="false" distributionRatio="1"/>
        <to uri="https://www.google.com"/>
    </loadBalance>
  </route>

</routes>
```

My Url:

```
http://localhost:8080/camel-example/camel/hello?bridgeEndpoint=true
```

i added **bridgeEndpoint=true** and removed also, i tried both ways. i'm getting same error.

please help me

```
how do I configure http urls in <to> tag.
```

Comment: <route>
     <from uri="servlet:///hello"/> 
     <to uri="http://localhost:8082/cdc/services/visamanager/getVisaListToGenerateDocs?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
     ....
    </route> 

**bridgeEndpoint=true** need to add in camel-config.xml like above, not in browser url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah the servlet component enriches the message with some HTTP related headers which the HTTP endpoint pickup and uses.

So what you need to do is to remove these headers before routing to the http uri.

```
<from uri="servlet:///hello"/>
<removeHeaders pattern="CamelHttp*"/>
...
```

There is a FAQ at the Camel website about this: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-remove-the-http-protocol-headers-in-the-camel-message.html